# HashMap length in vyper

Tags: vyper

Is there a way to access the number of elements in a hashmap? I can't find any instructions about this in the documentation and nothing I've tried seems to work.

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible to get the number of elements in a hashmap in Vyper since it is an implementation of a hash table.

From the Vyper [documentation](https://docs.vyperlang.org/en/latest/types.html#mappings):

> Mappings are hash tables that are virtually initialized such that every possible key exists and is mapped to a value whose byte-representation is all zeros: a type’s default value.

> The key data is not stored in a mapping. Instead, its keccak256 hash is used to look up a value. For this reason, mappings do not have a length or a concept of a key or value being “set”.